# Spark CollectPartitions slows with later partitions

Tags: java, apache-spark

We are processing a file with 120 partitions. Since we have to collect all partitions, rather than collect all at once, we are using collectPartitions, collecting 20 partitions at a time. This seems to work but with later partitions, it because too slow. Please see attached. What could be causing this behavior?

[Screen print of Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp1gM.png)

Comment: The question that has to be asked is - why do you use collectPartitions? collect means that all of the distributed dataset is collected to the driver program. If you're talking about a large volume of data, it shouldn't come as a surprise - you're putting too much gc pressure on the driver, and eventually you might even encounter OOM. Collect should be therefore applied with cautiousness, only when data is small enough

Comment: Requirement is to process entire data. What are the available options. collectPartitions was suggested as an alternate. But this seems to not work.

Comment: In addition, we are testing on a server with 192 GB RAM. File is 20 GB. We are getting out of memory for collect. So we are trying to collect by partitions.

Comment: What do you mean process the data? Processing is not the aim, it's the mean. What do you need to do with the processed data - save it somewhere?

Comment: We get structured data that we need to apply business rules on. Once we apply business rules, we collect all data, apply logic that identifies related data among the dataset and stores all data into a RDBMS.

Comment: OK, so the idea in spark is that unless you have very small amount of data that you can collect, let the executors do the work (including writing to RDBMS)